# traversing xml file structure and storing them for later use in hashmaps in java

Tags: java, xml, hashmap

I've XML file structure for single table node as below

```
<table ID="123" Name="Prj">
  <select>
        <slno>prjslno</slno>
        <to>prjrecepient</to>
        <from>prjsender</from>
        <body>prjcontent</body>
  </select>
  <where>status="new"</where>
  <successupdate>
        <status>'mail sent'</status>
  </successupdate>
  <failureupdate>
        <status>'mail sending failed'</status>
  </failureupdate>
</table>
```

There are 3 such nodes in my xml file. I need to traverse the xml file and store the content in hashmap.I've tried to store them in the following format

```
key     value
slno    prjslno
to      prjrecepient
from    prjsender
body    prjcontent
where   status="new"
```

But when I tried to store the status and its value for success and failure updates its getting overwritten and storing 'mail sending failed' value but not 'mail sent'.( I know the reason as the hashmap supports unique key so its storing in this way).

But I need to store them in hashmap for the later use. Is there any way to sort out? please suggest something.

Comment: Show us the java code you've written so far, and we'll have a better basis for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create composite keys from the current and it's parent element name, like:

```
 map.put("succesupdate/status", "'mail sent'");
 map.put("failureupdate/status", "'mail sending failed'");
```

It will not work in general but could be a solution for your current problem.